# (Typescript) Import json into Angular 4 project

Tags: json, angular, typescript

I have a json file of translations that I want to use in my angular 4 project. The file is also used in php which is why it needs to be stored as json rather than as a js module.

It has this structure

```
export interface IDictionary {
    amsterdamCenter: number[];
    amsterdamBounds: Array<number[]>;
    prices: Price[];
    cuisines: Object;
    areas: Object;
}
```

Following https://hackernoon.com/import-json-into-typescript-8d465beded79 I have changed typings.d.ts to read

```
/* SystemJS module definition */
declare var module: NodeModule;
interface NodeModule {
  id: string;
}

declare module "*.json" {
  const value: any;
  export default value;
}
```

Now I have an error with

```
import * as dictionary from './dictionary.json';

export const Dictionary: IDictionary = dictionary;
```

> [ts] Type 'typeof "*.json"' is not assignable to type 'IDictionary'. Property 'amsterdamCenter' is missing in type 'typeof "*.json"'.

However

```
export const Dictionary: any = dictionary;
```

does work. I'm hoping there is an incantation of TS that will permit me to import typescript using my interfaces

Comment: Are you using Typescript 2+ version? did you add the module declaration in the type definition file?

Comment: Also are you using webpack?

Comment: In linked example there's "casting" to `any`, so: `export const Dictionary: IDictionary = dictionary as any;`

Comment: Yes, typescript 2.2. I did add the type definition. I'm using angular cli which is webpack

Comment: @AlekseyL. yes I think I can see that that is the problem. By typings.d.ts seems very low level file ad so I did not want to put IDictionary there

Comment: I will check later, but I think you can change import to `import dictionary from './dictionary.json';` and no additional casting will be needed (as it is already defined as `any`)

Comment: I gave it a try but dictionary is then `undefined`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@simon-h try this code. Its working fine

```
import * as dictionary from './dictionary.json';

export const Dictionary: IDictionary = (<any>dictionary);
```

(or)

```
export const Dictionary: any = (<any>dictionary);
```

(or)

```
export const Dictionary: any = dictionary as any;
```

Answer (score 1):

One thing you could do is parse the Json file like :

```
import * as myJson from './my-json.json';

getMyJson(): Array<any> {
 return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(myJson))
}
```

you can type the response to a specific model/class if you wish.

EDIT: Actually just import and assign, copy if you wish:

```
import * as settingsMenu from './settings-menu.json';
const array = settingsMenu;
// OPTIONAL: copy object
const menu: Array<BdbMap> = new Array();
Object.assign(menu, array);
```